# httppost Android not work on some device

Tags: android, http-post

i want to send data from android device to my server using httpost. My code is like this

```
public void getData(String nama, String phone, String email) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("contact_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(nama, "UTF-8"); 

    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("phone", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8"); 

    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");


    String text = "";
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    try
        { 
    // Defined URL  where to send data
    URL url = new URL(apiLocation+"contact/testConnection");

    // Send POST data request

    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
    conn.setDoOutput(true); 
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
    wr.write( data ); 
    wr.flush(); 

    // Get the server response 

    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    // Read Server Response
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        // Append server response in string
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }

    text = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            reader.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }

    // Show response on activity
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The problem is, my code work fine on emulator using platform 2.3.3, I try to install on my device Android 2.3 also work fine. But not work when i try to install emulator platform 4.2.2 or another device Android 4.3. i have already adding Internet permission on manifest. there's any additional step that i must do ? i have no clue ....

Comment: Are you using `Asynctask` or `Thread` for Network Operations ?

Comment: can you please post error log ?

Comment: There is a Toast in that code. So we can conclude that no thread or AsyncTask is used. And there will be a NetworkOnMainThreadException clearly visible in the LogCat.